# Copy Html page source code to clipboard with JS

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard, clipboarddata

I've been trying to copy an html page's source code through the click of a button currently I'm getting an error that i've pasted below. I'm not familiar with the .execCommand function and why it's blowing up in this instance.

> Uncaught TypeError: body.execCommand is not a function
>           at copy (index.js:8)
>           at HTMLButtonElement. (index.js:14)

**The code:**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(event) {
  console.log("Domload")
  document.designMode = "on"
  var mode = document.designMode

    function copy(){
    body =  document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0]
    body.execCommand('copy')
    // .execCommand("copy")
    }

    var button = document.getElementsByClassName("copybutton")
    console.log(button)
    button[0].addEventListener("click",function(){copy()})


})
```

Comment: `execCommend` is not a method attached to the body element. It is a member of `document`. You want `document.execCommand('copy')`

Comment: When you say page source do you mean you want the HTML markup? Or do you just want the text that's on the page? `execCommand()` is only going to copy the text that is selected on the page, not the HTML structure.

Comment: @skyline3000 ideally, I'd like to be able to copy the html structure, currently trying to use a textbox to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Bro Code seems to be perfect but little problem is  you forgot to define body as variable  so instead

```
body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
```

Replace it with

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
```

See Magic happens .